# Adblock issue - chrome don't load external links like CSS, JS and images

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, load, external-links

When open this website: http://codeera.net/adlink/

in any browser except Google chrome 
work without issues, 
But when open this website in Google chrome I get a HTML page 
without CSS, JS and images (all of external links)

Comment: Try clearing your cache or incognito mode? Also observe the network tab in developer tools.

Comment: i tried to did this and no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because AdBlock, if you disable it everything will be ok. 
and just try to rename your title as "Ad" will activate AdBlock, I guess.

Comment: many thanks , it worked , but how i can avoid this issue for users who using 
AdBlock

Comment: change url name avoid using "Ad"

Comment: Great , It worked :) 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock looks for elements or attributes with 'ad' keyword to block them.